# Regex to check if a pattern occours at least N times

Tags: regex, postgresql

I am looking to do some password validation in postgres and need to check for minimum occurrences of certain characters, for example

```
select 'my_little_password' ~ '.*[0-9].*' /* false needs minimum one number */
select 'my_1st_password' ~ '.*[0-9].*' /* true has one number */
select 'my_1st_password' ~ '.*[0-9].*[0-9].*' /* false needs minimum two numbers */
select 'my_1st_password2' ~ '.*[0-9].*[0-9].*' /* true has two numbers */
```

Is there a way to do this in a smart way so I can just say, for example 99 numbers minimum? Not only am I reading the number `N` from a config file but I have to do this for lower case letters (`[a-z]`), upper case letters (`[A-Z]`) and special characters (`[-@_!#$%^&*()<>?/\|}{~:]`)

Comment: Unrelated to your question: Please don't implement such rules. They are annoying and don't help much to enforce strong passwords, see [this paper](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/1866307.1866327). NIST reccommends to skip such character composition rules too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```sql
select 'my_little_password' ~ '([^0-9]*[0-9]){N}'
```

where `N` = expected number of repeats.

**Example** for 99 digits:

```sql
([^0-9]*[0-9]){99}
```

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1 (99 times):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^0-9]*                  any character except: '0' to '9' (0 or
                             more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]                    any character of: '0' to '9'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ){99}                    end of \1
```

Comment: I don't mean to be demanding, but could you provide an example for min: 1 number (`[0-9]`), 2 lower case (`[a-z]`) 3 upper case (`[A-Z]`) and 4 special characters (`[*@#$]`) to demonstrate for more complex cases

Comment: @puk `^(?=.*?[0-9])(?=(?:.*?[a-z]){2})(?=(?:.*?[A-Z]){3})(?=(?:.*?[*@#$]){4})`